# How to call Microsoft oauth2 access token by HttpClient with certificate

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

by the following code I get a access/refresh token from oauth2 token Microsoft endpoint (for after calling Microsoft Graph API):

```
string url = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token", tenantId);

        Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "client_id", clientId },
            { "scope", "user.read offline_access openid place.read.all" },
            { "client_secret", clientSecret },
            { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
            { "code", authorizationCode }
        };

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(redirectUri))
        {
            values.Add("redirect_uri", redirectUri);
        }

        FormUrlEncodedContent data = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, data).Result;
```

But now I need to use a X509Certificate2, how I can replace the client secret by the certificate plz ? (how to passe the certificate instead client secret)
BTW if you can tell me how to make the refresh calling too, it will be very useful, bellow my code:

```
 string url = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token", tenantId);

        Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "client_id", clientId },
            { "scope", "user.read offline_access openid place.read.all" },
            { "client_secret", clientSecret },
            { "grant_type", "refresh_token" },
            { "refresh_token", refreshToken }
        };

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(redirectUri))
        {
            values.Add("redirect_uri", redirectUri);
        }

        FormUrlEncodedContent data = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, data).Result;
```

I precise that I can't use MSAL, is why I make a Http calling and I provided a authorization code generated by a sign-in user and I must keep it too.

thank a lot and best regards
Adrien

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. 
Doing so helps others find answers to their questions.

Comment: now trying to the moment I waiting the certificate from my architect

Answer (score 1):

Client assertions can be used anywhere a client secret would be used. As you are using the authorization code flow, you can pass in a client_secret to prove that the request is coming from your app. You can replace this with client_assertion and client_assertion_type parameters. Take a look at [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials) to know more about the certificate credential

Authorization code flow to access token with a certificate credential - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token-with-a-certificate-credential

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview)
and use below code to get the access token

```
 IConfidentialClientApplication ica = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithCertificate(GetCertByThumbprint(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, thumbPrint))
                .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token")
                .Build();
 AuthenticationResult authResult = await ica.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
 accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;
```

Then you can use that token to access your resource

```
 var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
 httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
 httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```